# adding columns in table

Tags: tables

I am using a table I have already formatted (thanks to this community) as a template for a table for summary statistics. This second table requires more columns and I am wondering how I can add these. Thanks for the help!

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage[symbol]{footmisc}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, tabularx}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\setcellgapes{2pt}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{textcomp}


%TABLE:
    \begin{table}[htbp]
\caption{Summary Statistics}

\label{tab:table1}
    \raggedright
Measures of CEO compensation. 

    \medskip
    \setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}
    \small
    \makegapedcells
\begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{@{}Lll @{}}
    \toprule
\thead[l]{Variable\\} 
            &  \thead[l]{N\\} 
                                & \thead[l]{Mean}\\ \\


Intercept   &  434.319        & 6250.899          \\
Stock awards (\%~Change)
            & -0.318 (.083)   & -2.638 (1.551)       \\
    \addlinespace
Total Compensation   & 0.253             & 0.062             \\
F-statistic & 145.65$^{*}$   & 34.10$^{*}$    \\
Sample Size & 11537         & 11529          \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\smallskip
$^{*}$ Significant at the 1\% level.
    \end{table}
```

[image]

Edit

@zarko, that didn't really do the trick!

Here's some code:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}


\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, tabularx}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\setcellgapes{2pt}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{graphicx}


\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell}
\usepackage[referable]{threeparttablex}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}

\begin{sidewaystable}
    \centering
    \sisetup{input-symbols = {( - )},
             table-space-text-post=***,
             }
    \renewcommand\arraystretch{0.9}
    \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Household Production Minutes: Full Sample}
\label{tab:min}
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}
                    l
               *{6}{S[table-format=3.3]}
                                        }
    \toprule
    &   \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textit{Female:}}
                    &   \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textit{Male:}}  \\
    \cmidrule{2-4}\cmidrule{5-7}
    & {\makecell[b]{Total\\ Household\\ Production}}
        & {\makecell[b]{Chore\\ Minutes}}
            & {\makecell[b]{Parenting\\ Minutes}}
                & {\makecell[b]{Total\\ Household\\ Production}}
                    & {\makecell[b]{Chore\\ Minutes}}
                        & {\makecell[b]{Parenting\\ Minutes}}  \\
     & {(1)} & {(2)} & {(3)} & {(4)} & {(5)} & {(6)}        \\
    \midrule
Income Share
    & -11.280           & -44.380\tnote{***}& 54.654\tnote{**}
    & -27.438\tnote{***}& -23.011\tnote{***}& -7.523        \\
    & (17.360)          & (12.041)          & (25.994)
    & (6.601)           & (4.429)           & (7.563)       \\
    \addlinespace
Education Difference
    & -6.791            & -1.060            & -12.021\tnote{*}
    & -2.431            & -2.362            & 1.915         \\
    & (4.760)           & (3.302)           & (6.788)
    & (2.147)           & (1.440)           & (2.409)       \\
    \addlinespace
Age & -1.541\tnote{**}  & 1.218\tnote{***}  & -5.477\tnote{***}
    & -0.823\tnote{***} & 0.022             & -1.812\tnote{***}  \\
    & (0.604)           & (0.419)           & (1.138)
    & (0.263)           & (0.176)           & (0.388)       \\
    \addlinespace
Log Household Income
    & -8.409            & -6.143            & -2.835
    & -3.038            & -4.194\tnote{**}  & 2.595         \\
    & (7.133)           & (4.947)           & (9.834)
    & (3.159)           & (2.120)           & (3.570)       \\
    \addlinespace
Work Minutes
    & -0.424\tnote{***} & -0.227\tnote{***} & -0.275\tnote{***}
    & -0.106\tnote{***} & -0.062\tnote{***} & -0.084\tnote{***}  \\
    & (0.018)           & (0.012)           & (0.024)
    & (0.009)           & (0.006)           & (0.010)       \\
    \addlinespace
Child 0-5
    & 172.346\tnote{***}& -5.395            & 112.881\tnote{***}
    & 34.885\tnote{***} & 0.746             & 19.181\tnote{***}  \\
    & (10.328)          & (7.163)           & (11.468)
    & (4.545)           & (3.050)           & (4.082)       \\
    \addlinespace
Child 6-18
    & 44.392\tnote{***} & 30.974\tnote{***} &
    & 7.323\tnote{**}   & 3.750             &               \\
    & (8.366)           & (5.803)           &
    & (3.704)           & (2.485)           &               \\
    \addlinespace
High School
    & 14.358            & 11.918            & 13.574
    & 2.479             & 0.665             & -1.509        \\
    & (14.103)          & (9.782)           & (35.007)
    & (6.961)           & (4.671)           & (12.953)      \\
    \addlinespace
College
    & 11.746            & 1.660             & 26.062
    & 6.437             & 1.397             & -1.739        \\
    & (15.879)          & (11.014)          & (36.345)
    & (7.461)           & (5.006)           & (13.706)      \\
    \addlinespace
Spouse High School
    & 0.735             & -3.638            & 9.136
    & -1.743            & 1.624             & -4.717        \\
    & (10.900)          & (7.561)           & (16.345)
    & (4.476)           & (3.003)           & (5.476)       \\
    \addlinespace
Spouse College
    & -2.203            & -2.939            & -6.558
    & 2.470             & 2.046             & -2.122        \\
    & (10.975)          & (7.612)           & (13.023)
    & (4.639)           & (3.113)           & (4.364)       \\
    \midrule
Observations
    & {1,538}           & {1,538}           & {1,013}
    & {1,539}           & {1,539}           & {1,014}       \\
R$\tnote{2}$
    & {0.546}           & {0.314}           & {0.367}
    & {0.178}           & {0.112}           & {0.155}       \\
Adjusted R$\tnote{2}$
    & {0.543}           & {0.309}           & {0.361} 
    & {0.173}           & {0.106}           & {0.147}       \\
Residual Std. Error
    & 146.365           & 101.519           & 144.965
    & 65.110            & 43.686            & 52.256        \\
(df)& {(1,526)}         & {(1,526)}         & {(1,002)}
    & {(1,527)}         & {(1,527)}         & {(1,003)}     \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular*}
    \begin{tablenotes}[flushleft, para]\footnotesize
\note: \item[*] $p<$0.1; \item[**] $p<0.05$; \item[***] $p<0.01$
    \end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
    \end{sidewaystable}
```

And the result:

[image]

Comment: off-topic for your question, but you might want to look at the siuntx package for a better alignment of the numbers.

Comment: simple add more column specifier, for example, instead `\begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{@{}Lll @{}}` in case of seven columns write `\begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{@{} L ll  ll ll @{}}`. in table body all cells in one row should be separated by `&`. i suggest you to read some introductionory text about table writing, for example https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables.

Comment: While you wait for an answer to this question, can you go back to your previous ones and look if the answers solve your problems and accept them, if they do?

Comment: as example of (good design) table with summary statistic see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/428118/clines-in-regression-table-misaligned/428809#428809

Comment: @samcarter how do I accept answers in this forum? I would be happy to do that as you guys have been so helpful.

Comment: @zarko thanks! I will have a look and see how much of this I can use

Comment: @Zarko please see the original post. I had some trouble implementing the code from the post you linked me to. The result is actually quite hilarious.

Comment: @user159324, for acceptation an answer just click on check mark at top left side of answer. accepted answer solve your problem for you on the best way :-)

Comment: @user159324, you copy my answer to your question. this not help to solve your problem. try to design own table on in answer showed way. we haven't any information, how big is your table, does it need to be rotated or not etc. now is not clear what is your problem.

Comment: @user159324 See [How do you accept an answer?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1852)

Comment: @Zarko , sorry for not being specific. I would like to have the table only be the width of the column and to be rotated to be in line with the text

Comment: @Zarko looks like the table I posted is specifically a sideways table. Probably not ideal for what i'm trying to do.

Comment: Use `sidewaystable*` not `sidewaystable`.