# any suggestions to implement this table in LaTeX

Tags: tables, multirow, multicolumn

I really tried hard to do this on my own, but I keep failing.. any suggestions please. here is a picture for the table i want[image]

Here's what I've tried so far.

```
\begin{table}\centering
\begin{adjustbox}{max width=\textwidth}
\begin{tabular}{cccccccc}
\toprule
Variables & AGR & CONST & ENRG &   HH & MANF & MIN & TRSM \\
\midrule
Constant & 4.1189***& 2.3716***& 4.7062***& 2.6683 ***&2.746***& 3.432***& 3.472*** \\
& \multirow{2}{*}{(5.67)}& \multirow{2}{*}{(5.37)}& \multirow{2}{*}{(5.96)}& \multirow{2}{*}{(9.22)}& \multirow{2}{*}{(5.17)}& \multirow{2}{*}{(8.08)}& \multirow{2}{*}{(8.46)}\\

\addlinespace
\addlinespace  

NPL (-1) & 0.505***& 0.61*** & 0.046  & -0.171***&0.633***&0.691***& 0.108***   \\
& \multirow{2}{*}{(1.422)}& \multirow{2}{*}{(1.175)}& \multirow{2}{*}{(2.118)}& \multirow{2}{*}{(-2.363)}& \multirow{2}{*}{(2.118)}& \multirow{2}{*}{(3.243)}& \multirow{2}{*}{(2.852)}\\

\addlinespace
\addlinespace 
\addlinespace 
Specialization:Log (Loans-to-Assets) & 0.505***& 0.533***& 0.513***& 0.539***&0.519***& 0.512***&   0.542*** \\
& \multirow{2}{*}{(18.16)}& \multirow{2}{*}{(18.32)}& \multirow{2}{*}{(18.45)}& \multirow{2}{*}{(18.44)}& \multirow{2}{*}{(18.49)}& \multirow{2}{*}{(18.24)}& \multirow{2}{*}{(18.25)}\\
\addlinespace 
\addlinespace
\addlinespace 

Credit quality:Log (Loan loss provision-to-total loans) & 0.1113 & 2123.17 & \\

\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
        \end{adjustbox}
\caption{This table shows}\label{eval_table}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Hi there, could you show us one of your best attempts? It would save someone a lot of typing and might also enable them to give better, more detailed advice

Comment: What, specifically, about this table would you like to reproduce? The odd-looking font size changes? The relentless use of italics, which makes it needlessly hard to read the numbers? The huge amount of unmotivated whitespace in one of the rows? The lack of alignment of the numbers on the decimal markers? The overall "prison cell" look?

Comment: @Mico. The table has nothing that complex for someone who knows the basics of LaTeX. However, in the last 3 rows, there is one column that should be divided into multirow cells with three smaller cells to its side that will be properly aligned with the rest of the last three rows. This is really an interesting challenge.

Comment: @Al-MotasemAldaoudeyeh - Thanks. I think I will hold off providing table-related code until we hear back from the OP directly regarding which table features should be replicated.

Comment: @Al-MotasemAldaoudeyeh - Since the OP hasn't responded to my questions, I've gone ahead and posted an answer with *my* interpretation of how to make the tabular matter look reasonably alright.

Comment: that is one mysterious arrangements of the numbers in the cells... I'd suggest a d-column

Comment: @Mico haha I only now just read your comment. Remember: " Haithem is a new contributor. Be nice, and check out our Code of Conduct. " :D

Comment: @thymaro - Thanks! About being nice (and other things mentioned in the site's Code of Conduct): I sure hope that the OP wasn't taken aback by my (admittedly unvarnished, and maybe even scathing) assessment of the shortcomings of the table in the screenshot he/she posted. The old saying, "If you can't say something nice, don't say anything at all", isn't all that helpful if it's necessary to make improvements. My comments were certainly meant exclusively to be *ad rem*, not *ad hominem*.

Comment: @mico  , thanks for the help as you know i'm a  a new contibutor, i have tried to reproduce the same table here is my suggestions in the comment below

Answer (score 5):

The following solution seeks to avoid the rather questionable design elements of the table that's shown in the screenshot you posted and which I noted in an earlier comment.

The LaTeX code for the table shown below

- uses italics only sparingly, i.e., only in places where it makes sense to try to highlight something, and doesn't use **bold-facing** at all;
- uses no vertical lines and few, but well-spaced, horizontal lines to give the table an overall open and "inviting" look -- observe that whitespace can be every bit as effective as a solid line at creating a visual "barrier";
- employs the `dcolumn` package to align all numbers in the seven data columns on their respective decimal markers;
- refrains from making unmotivated changes in the font size; and
- doesn't needlessly insert vertical whitespace, and thus avoids creating pointless visual gaps.

[image]

```
\documentclass[times]{elsarticle} % as per the OP's earlier postings
\usepackage{booktabs}  % for well-spaced horizontal lines
\usepackage{dcolumn}   % to align numbers on decimal markers
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D..{#1}}
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}} % handy shortcut macro
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht!]
\footnotesize
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt} % make LaTeX figure out intercol. space
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} l *{7}{d{2.5}} }
\toprule
Variables & \mc{AGR} & \mc{CONST} & \mc{ENRG} 
          & \mc{HH} & \mc{MANF} & \mc{MIN} & \mc{TRSM}\\
\midrule
Constant  & 4.119^{***} &  2.372^{***} & 4.706^{***} & 2.668^{***} & 2.746^{***} & 3.432^{***} & 3.472^{***}\\
      & (5.57)      &  (5.37) \\   
\addlinespace
NPL($-1$) & 0.520^{***} &  \\
          & (18.16)     &  \\  
\addlinespace
\emph{Specialization}  \\
Log (Loans-to-Assets) & 0.505^{***}\\ 
                      & (1.422)    \\  
\addlinespace
\emph{Credit Quality} \\
Log (Loan loss provi-  & 0.361^{***}  & \\
\quad sions to total loans) & (11.47) & \\  
\addlinespace
Log (Diversification) & -0.022 & \\
                      & (-0.24)& \\  
\addlinespace
\emph{Profitability} & \\
Log (Return on Assets) & -0.091^{***} & \\   
                        & (-2.26)     & \\
\addlinespace
GDP \hfill Mov(2) & -0.039^{**} & -0.028^{**} & -0.109^{***}\\
                  & (2.75)      & (-2.31)     & (-3.51) \\ 
\addlinespace
\hfill Mov(3) & & & & -0.061^{***} & & -0.021^{**} & \\
              & & & & (-4.60)       & & (-1.03)      & \\
\addlinespace
\hfill Mov(4) & & & & & -0.044^{**} & & -0.045^{***}\\
              & & & & & (1.65)      & & (-3.42)\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: it sems that the definition of the `d` column has an error. i got error "run away argument". unfortunately i'm not familiar with `dcolumn` so i cant say what is wrong. also in `\newcommand\mc[2]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}}` you use only one argument ...

Comment: @zarko I tried to replicate your code but it reproduces me another figure, please can you find out the problem , or can we try to work on my suggestions , how to include the gdp column in my code

Comment: @Miko there a problem with code. please can you find out the error

Comment: @Zarko - Thanks for pointing out two slight issues in the code (related to the definitions of the `d` column type and the `\mc` macro). I've fixed them both now.

Comment: +1 This looks so much better than the original table! I am not familiar with the subject of the table, but the rows with `GDP` seem to be something different than the other rows, maybe set this apart by a `\midrule` above it?

Comment: @samcarter - Thanks! :-) I was actually also wondering about how the GDP rows might relate to the material above them -- and hence if it might be helpful to draw a `\midrule` rather than "just" provide a bit of whitespace, to provide a stronger visual offset. But, in view of the fact that the table in the OP's screenshot provides next to no visual guidance, I thought I'd keep things as neutral as possible. (For sure, I don't know if "GDP" is related to "Profitablity".) If the OP were to provide additional information about the intended structure, that would of course be very welcome.

Answer (score 3):

an example of the more complex solution than is provided by [Mico](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/5001/mico) .... beside the package `booktabs` it use packages `tabularx` `threeparttable` and `siunitx`:

**edit:**
in the first answer version i forgot on negative numbers in parentheses. now this is corrected:

```
\documentclass[times]{elsarticle}               % based on @Mico answer
\usepackage{booktabs, tabularx, threeparttable}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\newcommand\mcx[1]{%
    \multicolumn{1}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}{#1}} % for columns' headers

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht!]
\sisetup{input-symbols={( - )},
     table-align-text-post=false,
         parse-numbers=false,      % <---
         table-format=-2.5         % <---
     }
\linespread{0.9}

     \begin{threeparttable}[htb]
\caption{Table title}
\label{tab:statistic}
    \small
    \setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} l *{7}{S} @{}}
    \toprule
Variables & \mcx{AGR} & \mcx{CONST} & \mcx{ENRG}
          & \mcx{HH}  & \mcx{MANF}  & \mcx{MIN} & \mcx{TRSM}    \\
    \midrule
Constant    & 4.1189\tnote{***} & 2.3716 \tnote{***}    & 4.7062\tnote{***}
            & 2.6683\tnote{***} & 2.746\tnote{***}      & 3.432\tnote{***}
            & 3.472\tnote{***}  \\
            &   (5.67)          &   (5.37)              &   (5.96)
            &   (9.22)          &   (5.17)              &   (8.08)
            &   (8.46)          \\
    \addlinespace
NPL $(-1)$  & 0.505\tnote{***}  & 0.61\tnote{***}       & 0.046
            & -0.171\tnote{***} & 0.633\tnote{***}      & 0.691\tnote{***}
            & 0.108\tnote{***}  \\
            &   (1.422)         &   (1.175)             &   (2.118)
            &   (2.363)         &   (2.118)             &   (3.243)
            &   (2.852)         \\
    \midrule
GDP:\quad Mov(2)
            & -0.039\tnote{**}  & -0.028\tnote{**}      & -0.109\tnote{***}
            & & & &             \\
            &   (2.75)          &   (-2.31)             &   (-3.51)
            & & & &             \\
    \addlinespace
\hfill Mov(3)
            & & & & -0.061\tnote{***}   & & -0.021\tnote{**}    &       \\
            & & & &     (-4.60)         & &   (-1.03)           &       \\
    \addlinespace
\hfill Mov(4)
            & & & & & -0.044\tnote{**}  & & -0.045\tnote{***}           \\
            & & & & & (1.65)            & & (-3.42)                     \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\begin{tablenotes}[para]
    \item[*]    explanation what is *;
    \item[**]   explanation what is **;
    \item[**]   explanation what is ***;
\end{tablenotes}
    \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines indicate text border)

Comment: thanks for the help, there something else... in your code i can't include negatif number between bracket

Comment: ups, in form as it is, this is not possible. it seems that i forgot on something. i will check asap.

Comment: @Haithem, see edited answer.